# Resultant vector angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

Determine the magnitude and direction of a fourth vector $\vec{D}$ that when added to vectors $\vec{A}$,$\vec{B}$,$\vec{C}$ will yield a vector sum of zero. Make a sketch of vector D on a Cartesian coordinate system.

$$\vec{A} = 26\hat{i}+ 15\hat{j}$$ 
$$\vec{B} = -8\hat{i}+ 23\hat{j}$$
$$\vec{C} = -12\hat{i}- 14\hat{j}$$

For $\vec{D}$ I got $-6\hat{i} -24\hat{j}$ (When added with $\vec{A}$,$\vec{B}$,$\vec{C}$ = $0\hat{i}+0\hat{j}$)

Then I used Pythagorean theorem to find the magnitude of the resultant $\vec{D}$ vector to be
$$|\vec{D}|=\sqrt{(-6)^2+(-24)^2}\approx25$$

Then the angle $\displaystyle{tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-6}{-24}\right)}$ which resulted in $14^0$, but is that measured from the negative y axis? Should the angle really be $256^0$ if measured from the positive x-axis?

I drew this vector in the $3^{rd}$ quadrant

Comment: Hi Jessica and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  When you use a calculator to evaluate an inverse trig function, you must always stop to consider whether the calculator value is correct, or the ***other*** angle between 0 and 360 that satisfies the relationship is the one (Or both, perhaps!)

The tangent function is positive in the first and third quadrants (as you noted) so adding 180 to the calculator result leads to an alternate solution.

Some computer languages and some calculators have an ATAN2(x, y) function, that takes the x and y components of a vector, and gives the one correct value for the angle.

In addition, many calculators have a $(x, y)\text{ to } (r, \theta)$ function that does both of the steps you followed.

Answer (score 0):

Often calculators only consider a restricted range when calculating inverse trig functions (e.g. between -90 and +90). If this is the case, one work-around would be that you may draw the vector as $\vec{D}=-6\hat{i}-24\hat{j}$, and ask the question 'what is the angle between the $\vec{D}$ and the x-axis?'

To do this, draw the triangle (with only positive lengths) as your vector, a segment of the negative x-axis, and a line that connects the end of $\vec{D}$ to the negative x-axis, and then find the angle in the usual manner (using inverse trig functions). You will be guaranteed that you answer is between 0 and 90. Once you have this number, you may add it to 180$^o$ to find the full angle of $\vec{D}$ (as measured from the positive x-axis).